# pygame get key pressed as a string

Tags: python, pygame

I want to change the text in the controls screen based on the key which the user presses.
how do I convert `pygame.event.get()` into a string that shows which key has been pressed?

preferably without many if staments

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        slectedKey = # get key name as a string
        print(slectedKey)
```

Comment: `print(pygame.key.name(event.key))`

Answer (score 6):

The code of the pressed can be get by the `event.key` attribute. 
The unicode representation for the key can be get by the `event.unicode` attribute.
See [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module.

A unser friendly name of a key can be get by `pygame.key.name()`:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

        print(pygame.key.name(event.key))
```

---

Note, if you want to evaluate if a certain key is pressed, the compare `event.key` to the constants defined in the [`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) module:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            # [...]
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            # [...]
```

Or store the key in a variable and use it continuously in the application loop:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        slectedKey = event.key

if slectedKey == pygame.K_UP:
    # [...]
elif slectedKey == pygame.K_DOWN:
    # [...]
```

---

If you want to evaluate if a key is is hold down, the use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed):

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    # [...]
elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
    # [...]
```

Comment: the keydown event also has a `unicode` attribute which can be used directly.
It will come event for special keys, for which the `.key` attribute would be inorrect anyway (for example code "273" for up arrow key)

Comment: What (Unicode or otherwise) gets returned for the left shift key? Why not use `key.name`?

Comment: so `event.key` gives a number & `event.unicode` gives me the key but dosen't really work for the arrow keys (it returns them as a blank)

Comment: yeah I suppose I could do that for the keys that have no representable signs then just
 `else:
        slectedKey = event.unicode`

Comment: @Rabbid76 but I would still prefer if I didn't have to use a lot of elif statments

Comment: @Rabbid76 I want to print the selected key

Comment: I found this code wich seems to solve the problem(he did use sys tho)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47857397/12607177
Is there a way to do it without importing sys

Comment: @Avenger_aawin, Regarding the link you posted: read the code and search for `sys`, what do they use `sys` for? Do you need to do that? You can very quickly answer your own questions with a bit of research

Comment: See https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.name: "Get the descriptive name of the button from a keyboard button id constant."

Comment: @usr2564301 Thank you. You never stop learning ;-)